# NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, java-security

I'm trying to connect with PostgreSQL using ssl and getting exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not find a java cryptographic algorithm: Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13.
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:271)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractKeyManagerWrapper.getPrivateKey(SSLContextImpl.java:1765)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createClientPossession(X509Authentication.java:251)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:206)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.choosePossession(CertificateMessage.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1102)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:958)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:436)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.onConsumeFinished(Finished.java:1011)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.consume(Finished.java:874)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1382)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1295)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:534)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    ... 107 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.113549.1.5.13
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:565)
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:223)
    ... 144 common frames omitted
```

this is how i'm trying to connect

```
jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/dbname?sslmode=require&sslcert=D:\\work\\linux\\postgres-ssl\\postgresql.crt&sslkey=D:\\work\\linux\\postgres-ssl\\postgresql.pk8&sslrootcert=D:\\work\\linux\\postgres-ssl\\root.crt&sslpassword=password";`
```

i'm on springboot version 2.5.4 with Java 11. i created the certificates using openssl utility

**UPDATE:**

i created the key using `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES -inform PEM -outform DER -in postgresql.key -out postgresql.pk8` and now the exception is different

```
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Cannot retrieve the PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.getKeySpec(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:258)
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:257)
    ... 144 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:408)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:440)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.getKeySpec(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:253)
```

Comment: Did you use `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 $symcipher` or `openssl pkey -$symcipher`? Those create PKCS8 using PBES2 encryption, which Java can't handle using the simple `KeyFactory and Cipher for key.topalgorithm` method that works on PBES1 schemes. Try `pkcs8 -topk8 -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES` . (Or if the postgres driver supports it, which I don't know, _and_ your system is secure enough without it, don't encrypt the key at all.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 i tried with `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES -inform PEM -outform DER -in postgresql.key -out postgresql.pk8` and here's the exception i'm getting `Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
 at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
 at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)`

Comment: Faheem: BadPadding is almost always caused by wrong key, as it says, and in this case the key is derived from the passphrase. Check the passphrase. Especially if it contains any non-ASCII character(s) that may be handled differently by different programs.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you are right. you can put your comment as an answer so i can accept it